# background device music gets stopped as app starts ios

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, background-music

I am playing music in iphone and when I run my application it should not stop background device music and should stop its own music instead background music is getting stop. I want to do same as candy crush app. What should I do to resolve this? Please help me

```
    var isOtherAudioPlaying = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().otherAudioPlaying
      println("isOtherAudioPlaying>>> \(isOtherAudioPlaying)")
      if(isOtherAudioPlaying == false)
           {
            audioPlayer1!.play()
           }
```

Comment: You need to set your app's audio session category and options appropriately. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/index.html

Comment: It has been solved by following code:- **AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient, error: nil) == true** where i am placing my movieplayercontroller to play

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest checking out [Sameer's answer to this for Swift 2.0, just a few months back.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33228074/4851799) Works perfectly with Swift 2.0.

```
let sess = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
if sess.otherAudioPlaying {
    _ = try? sess.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient, withOptions: []) //
    _ = try? sess.setActive(true, withOptions: [])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the default is AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient, you need to set the proper category for your app and activate it. You could use AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient for mixing audio.

Add this in your AppDelegate.swift:

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
  AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient, error: nil)
  AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)
  // ...
}
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Defer `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)` till when you need to start playing audio. Starting the session immediately after the app launches stops playback on other apps.

More details:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession

Comment: I am facing one issue here as said am setting category at initial `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback, mode: .default)` and when I need to play audio in the app then just before that I am setting `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)`

but still other audio is pausing when opens the app, any idea

Comment: If you want your app's audio to mix with that of other apps, you should consider playing with other options for playback. 

For example, use `mixWithOthers`:
`AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: [.mixWithOthers])`

Comment: No I don't want the mixing sound, I am expecting my ios app should trump the apple music/other music audio, if audio was initiated in my ios app but not just by opening the app.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 10.3
Swift 4.2
Tested in iPhoneX (12.2), iPhone5s(11.0.3)

Functionality -> Play audio in silent mode + with other application audio.

Here is the code,

```
private func setupAudioSession() {
        //enable other applications music to play while quizView
        let options = AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions.mixWithOthers
        let mode = AVAudioSession.Mode.default
        let category = AVAudioSession.Category.playback
        try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(category, mode: mode, options: options)
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    }
```

I will suggest you to set this function in AppDelegate -> didFinishLaunchingWithOptions....

Comment: why did you use mixWithOthers? instead of Ambient?

Comment: @Emil
**AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers**Controls whether other active audio apps will be interrupted or mixed with when your app's audio session goes active. **MixWithOthers** is only valid with *AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord*,
            *AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback*, and *AVAudioSessionCategoryMultiRoute*.