# How can I allow background music to continue playing while my app still plays its sounds while using Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, audio, mobile

I created an app and I am attempting to allow the user to continue to listen to their music while playing my game, but whenever they hit "play" and the ingame sounds occur it will stop the background music.  I am developing on iOS using Swift. Here is a piece of the code that initiates the ingame sounds.

```
func playSpawnedDot() {
    var alertSound: NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("spawnDot", ofType: "mp3")!)!
    var error:NSError?
    audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: alertSound, error: &error)
    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()

    if volumeBool {
        audioPlayer.play()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You need to set the `AVAudioSession` category, with one of the following value: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/index.html (AVAudioSession Class Reference).

The default value is set to `AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient`. As you can read :

> [...] using this category implies that your app’s audio is nonmixable—activating your session will interrupt any other audio sessions which are also nonmixable. To allow mixing, use the `AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient` category instead.

You have to change the category, before you play your sound. To do so :

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient, error: nil)
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)
```

*You don't need to call those line each time you play the sound. You might want to do it only once.*

Comment: This no longer works in swift 2.0. Is there any updated code?

Comment: This worked for me        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }

Comment: If you're having trouble adapting this code to newer versions of Swift, try using something like this: `try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.ambient)`

Answer (score 19):

**Swift 4** version:

```
try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
```

Comment: Don't forget to `import AVFoundation`

Comment: Don't forget to set `setActive` to false once your sound is done playing, otherwise, the background music ducking will remain even after playback has finished.

Answer (score 15):

**This is how I do it in Swift 3.0**

```
var songPlayer : AVAudioPlayer?         

func SetUpSound() {


        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "TestSound", ofType: "wav") {
            let filePath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:path)
            songPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer.init(contentsOf: filePath as URL)
            songPlayer?.numberOfLoops = -1 //logic for infinite loop
            songPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
            songPlayer?.play()
        }

        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        try!audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.duckOthers) //Causes audio from other sessions to be ducked (reduced in volume) while audio from this session plays  
}
```

You can see more of AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avaudiosessioncategoryoptions

Comment: move (let audioSession... ) AND (try!audioSession...) lines to above the if condition to get better result . background music don't stop for first time too . ( I'm inserted func SetUpSound() code in a button action )

Comment: @Hamid Reza Ansari - Your comment saved my day. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

Here's what I am using for Swift 2.0:

```
let sess = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
if sess.otherAudioPlaying {
    _ = try? sess.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient, withOptions: .DuckOthers)
    _ = try? sess.setActive(true, withOptions: [])
}
```

Please note that you can replace `.DuckOthers` with `[]` if you don't want to lower background music and instead play on top to it.

Answer (score 5):

lchamp's solution worked perfectly for me, adapted for Objective-C:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
```

Answer (score 5):

Since they can't seem to make up their minds from version to version. Here it is in Swift 5.0

```
do{
   try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.ambient)
   try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
} catch {
   NSLog(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**

### Updated for Swift 3.0

**

The name of the sound I am playing is shatter.wav

```
func shatterSound() {
    if let soundURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "shatter", withExtension: "wav") {
        var mySound: SystemSoundID = 0
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundURL as CFURL, &mySound)
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(mySound);
    }
}
```

Then where ever you want to play the sound call

```
shatterSound()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to play an alert sound:

```
public func playSound(withFileName fileName: String) {

    if let soundUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "wav") {
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient, with:[.duckOthers])
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

            var soundId: SystemSoundID = 0

            AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundUrl as CFURL, &soundId)
            AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion(soundId, nil, nil, { (soundId, clientData) -> Void in
                AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundId)
                do {
                    // This is to unduck others, make other playing sounds go back up in volume
                    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(false)
                } catch {
                    DDLogWarn("Failed to set AVAudioSession to inactive. error=\(error)")
                }
            }, nil)

            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundId)
        } catch {
            DDLogWarn("Failed to create audio player. soundUrl=\(soundUrl) error=\(error)")
        }
    } else {
        DDLogWarn("Sound file not found in app bundle. fileName=\(fileName)")
    }
}
```

And if you want to play music:

import AVFoundation

```
var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer?

public func playSound(withFileName fileName: String) {

    if let soundUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "wav") {
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient, with:[.duckOthers])
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

            let player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundUrl)
            player.delegate = self
            player.prepareToPlay()
            DDLogInfo("Playing sound. soundUrl=\(soundUrl)")
            player.play()
            // ensure the player does not get deleted while playing the sound
            self.audioPlayer = player
        } catch {
            DDLogWarn("Failed to create audio player. soundUrl=\(soundUrl) error=\(error)")
        }
    } else {
        DDLogWarn("Sound file not found in app bundle. fileName=\(fileName)")
    }
}

func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
    self.audioPlayer?.stop()
    do {
        // This is to unduck others, make other playing sounds go back up in volume
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(false)
    } catch {
        DDLogWarn("Failed to set AVAudioSession inactive. error=\(error)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For Swift (Objective-C like this too)

you can use [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dqad3XuMwHI) link for best answer and if you don't have any time for watching 10 minutes the best action is that you just `copy` below code in your `AppDelegate` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and then select your `project's target` then go to `Capabilities` and at last in `Background modes` check on `Audio, AirPlay and Picture in Picture`

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
    }
    catch {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't think that just setting the AVAudioSession to AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.duckOthers would work, but it did. Here is my full code to help the rookies like myself.

**Swift 4 - Full Example**:

```
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()


func playSound(sound: String){
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: sound, ofType: nil)!
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    try!audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.duckOthers)

    do {
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        audioPlayer.play()
    } catch {
        print("couldn't load the file")
    }
}
```

I still need to figure out setActive ([I was looking at this blog post](http:////TODO%20research%20setActive%20more%20-%20https://thedon.me/2016/03/15/avaudiosession-and-ducking/)) but the audio stops ducking when I leave the app, so it works for my app.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 Version based on lchamp`s answer.

```
try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.ambient)
try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly for me on **iOS 14.4 and Swift 5**. It's a bit different answer from others by using the `.duckOthers` option (and you can also mix directly with sound if you'd like with `.mixWithOthers`), but it works perfectly while music plays. It will lower the volume of the music, play the "beep" sound, and then raise the music volume back up to normal. It also captures error data using Google Firebase Crashlytics if there is an issue, and tries to raise the volume to normal even on an error.

This code will also work perfectly on the first, and all other, plays of your sound without it stopping the music ever.

```
func playSound() {
    do {
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "beep", ofType: "mp3") {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: .duckOthers)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            
            let filePath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:path)
            songPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer.init(contentsOf: filePath as URL)
            songPlayer?.numberOfLoops = 0
            songPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
            songPlayer?.play()
            
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(false)
        }
    } catch (let error) {
        try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(false)
        Crashlytics.crashlytics().setCustomValue(error.localizedDescription, forKey: "audio_playback_error")
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this deactivate the audio session right away without playing the sound?

Answer (score 0):

An important thing the others answers do not have is that you need to call false with the .notifyOthers flag when deactivating:

```
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(false, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
```

The reason for this is that other apps playing music in the background will know when to turn their audio back on when you deactivate yours. Otherwise your background music won't turn back on if you turned off your session.