# Background music stops when app launches and when using SKAction.playSoundFileNamed

Tags: ios, swift, audio, background-music

I am using Swift

When I launch or resume my game it pauses the background music. I found that when I invoke `SKAction.playSoundFileNamed`, it pauses background music.

How can I stop the background music from pausing?

Thanks!

Comment: do you mean music playing from the music directory?

Comment: No I mean music playing from SoundCloud or Spotify etc.

Comment: then yes same thing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29024320/how-can-i-allow-background-music-to-continue-playing-while-my-app-still-plays-it