# SwiftUI - AudioRecorder stop all device sounds

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avaudiosession, avaudiorecorder

I'm trying to record sound with my Ipad while a video/music is playing with SwiftUI. But when I start AVAudioSession, my device sounds cut off, while I would like my video/music sound to continue. To sum up, I would like, if possible, to record sound and listen to a video / music simultaneously (a bit like when you make a snap with music).

I found almost nothing, I tried changing the recording session settings : `recordingSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default, options: .mixWithOthers)`
but I can't find the solution.

My Ipad is on IOS 15.5, so rather recent...

Comment: Maybe it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29024320/how-can-i-allow-background-music-to-continue-playing-while-my-app-still-plays-it