# Music plays alongside sounds but pauses music upon initial launch. How to let background music keep playing when launched?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, sprite-kit

I followed this post: [SKAction playSoundFileNamed stops background music](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21835402/skaction-playsoundfilenamed-stops-background-music) and it worked in that background music was no longer paused when SK sound actions were run.

Unfortunately thought music is still stopped when the app is launched initially. I also tried code from another post ([background device music gets stopped as app starts ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28194514/background-device-music-gets-stopped-as-app-starts-ios)) but that either didn't work.

How do I stop my app from pausing music upon the initial launch? Maybe I am not placing my code in the right location?

Code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
        } catch _ {
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Thanks!

EDIT 1 (for use from comments)

`func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
        } catch _ {
        }
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        } catch _ {
        }
    }`

Comment: post some code and we could tell you,  that is exactly how to keep music playing

Comment: you do not set active to true

Comment: Do you mean I should be returning false?

Comment: No, you need to set active to true in the shared instance, look at the 2nd example you provided

Comment: I put ```do {
      try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    } catch _ {
    }``` inside the applicationDidBecomeActive and it did not work. I also put it inside the didFinishingLaunching function and it did not work. Where should I put it?

Comment: did you do it exactly as the example shows

Comment: Hey. Just updated my post with what my new code looks like. Had to convert to new swift but otherwise it's what that posts 1st answer says to do